# Get uncommon words from sentence

Tags: regex

I need a function that can take a sentence and extract only the uncommon words.

I was thinking to build a dictionary that will hold the common words for each language.
Then I will search each word from my sentence (one by one) against this dictionary, and that way I can tell if it common or uncommon.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That would be a pretty big list, no?  Is there any other way of testing a word for its common-ness?

Comment: If you give a rating to every word in language, then yes it's gonna be a big list. No way around it. Are you sure you don't want to find common words in input based on the occurrence in input itself?

Comment: Follow the 20/80 rule: 20% of the words in a language is used 80% of the time. So it make more sense to create a dictionary of **common** words. For English, this number is about 7000 words for 90% of the cases.

Comment: I believe even less, I believe it’s around 1000 words for each language.
Maybe it’s better to check the input and separate the uncommon words when the message arrive.
This is a chat instant messaging application based on ejabberd, I am not shore if I can have a licenser that can catch each message and examine it.